# Booking time slots in Liferay Calendar

Tags: calendar, liferay, appointment

I would like to implement an appointment system in Liferay Calendar.
In Liferay Calendar if two users are logged in and one of them books a particular time slot, then the other user should not be able to book the same slot. In other words that particular slot should be disabled.

Comment: As far as I remember, there is the concept of resources in the calendar - maybe that could help?

Comment: That doesn't help. I need the 2 users to book different time slots as in a particular time slot should be disabled as soon as it is booked.